# Vis.js throwing exception after switching to network version

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am using `vis.js` `4.18.1` currently for a project, which is running on **IE11**. So far everything worked good, but now I'm trying to add extra functionality for adding edges, etc, and when working on the events, I didn't have my `controlNodeDragEnd` event fired and I thought its not in my version yet and anyway it would be better to use the latest version (I already had a lot of work done, when i realized I am using the old github project)...So, long story short, I downloaded the latest `vis-network.js` and the corresponding CSS file. Exchanged it with the old ones and now I get the following error when trying to display my diagram:

> SCRIPT5007: Object.getPrototypeOf: 'this' is not an Object
>   vis-network.js (7074,9)

I am not using `npm`, I need the `js` file in my project, am I missing some dependencies maybe? 
Didn't change anything else, all my networks were displayed without error in 4.18 and 4.21.

Comment: After some debugging, I found out, that when 

if (b[prop] && Object.getPrototypeOf(b[prop]) === Object.prototype) {

gets to property scaleFactor, the exception happens. 

I tried removing almost everything from options, but it didn't help unfortunately...

Comment: Ok, as I see, its internet explorer :(

Answer (score 0):

The reason is a known bug, already in progress:

https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/57

Closing question, this should fix it, when finished.